# In tableau, i want to hide alternative rows

Tags: tableau-api

In tableau, I want to hide alternative rows like:
I have 2 columns name as ID , Name

```
id  name
101  x
102  y 
103  z
104  a
```

Now I want:

```
id  name
101  x
102  
103  z
104
```

Comment: What do you consider an alternate row? An even-numbered id value?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to do this simply, as in there is no option dealing with "alternative rows"  in Tableau.

Given the sample data provided though, you could create a calculated field to determine the sequence of data you are displaying.  For example, the table functions RANK_UNIQUE or INDEX could sequentially assign an integer to your data within the partition. You can then use

```
[Even_or_odd]:
IF [Sequence_Number] % 2 = 0
THEN "Even"
ELSE "Odd"
```

You could then use this calculated field to drive a second that would go along the lines of:

```
[Display_Value]:
IF [Even_or_odd] = Odd
THEN NULL
ELSE [Value]
```